# I want to start my portfolio site using ASP.Net and I'm a bit lost about hwo to actually put it on the web

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, website, url

I found this site:

www.discountasp.net

They seem cheap enough and have a track record. I decided to host my site with them. Here's where I'm confused.

I host the application (my website) with them and they give me an IP address, right? Users can visit my site by typing in that IP address right? (Of course once I move the index file and create a defauly web folder, etc.)

Next step is buying a domain name right? Like www.mysite.com, right?

Is this the way it's done, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`I host the application (my website) with them and they give me an IP address, right?`

Correct

`Users can visit my site by typing in that IP address right?`

No. Your IP address will be shared with dozens, or even hundreds of other websites. Your host will use a feature in IIS called "Hostname Bindings" which will make YOUR website be displayed when the critera for the hostname is matched.

`Next step is buying a domain name right? Like www.mysite.com, right?`

Sort of. You should really have your domain name BEFORE you choose a hosting package, but you can do it in either order.

There is a missing step there though. Once you have your domain name, you then connect it to a DNS provider (who map your domain name to an IP address), and your DNS provider connects your domain name with the IP in question 1.

Your DNS provider can often be your registrar, or your hosting provider, or another 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll typically buy (well, register) a domain name, then give that domain name to your hosting provider who will setup the web server to serve your website whenever a request for that domain name comes in.  The processes by which you setup your domain and upload your content will be specific to the hosting company, and you should contact their support department for help with that.  If they don't give you the support you need, well, perhaps choosing someone with "discount" in the name isn't the way to get good support...

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get it online on the web, you'll first need to buy some hosting space, and a domain name (like something.com)... i recommend hostingfest.com for your space as they have the cheapest windows plans EVER found on the net (starting at a $1.99/month)... and name.com for your domain purchase...

Since the IP address the host gives you will be shared amongst some other dozen accounts, you'll need to buy a domain to link your account to it (hence the domain name), and you'll need some web space to host your files on the web (Hence the hosting companies)...

I hope i answered your question completely... ask away my friend if u need anything else...